# System errors with Navigation Block

Tags: navigation

We are receiving system errors as follows and these have only just began appearing, I am not sure if coincidence but it seems to have started since we introduced iphone theme design exception in the backend;

> ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 9 for
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(), called
>   in /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php on line 455  and
>   defined  in /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php on line
>   228 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: rendermode  in
>   app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php on line 294 ERR (3):
>   Notice: Undefined variable: rendermode  in
>   app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php on line 296

We do have a custom theme local Navigation.php file present and code has been added around the error lines 294 & 296 to display category images as follows (I have bold text lines 294 & 296);

```
// assemble list item with attributes
    $htmlLi = '<li';
    foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
        $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
    }
    $htmlLi .= '>';
    $html[] = $htmlLi;
    **if($rendermode == 'image' && $this->getImageUrl($category)){**
       $html[] = '<img src="'.$this->getImageUrl($category).'" />';
      **}else if($rendermode == 'thumbnail' && $this->getThumbnailUrl($category)){**
       $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"><img src="'.$this-      >getThumbnailUrl($category).'" /></a>';
      }
```

Is this code causing the errors and how to go about fixing? Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that someone (maybe you) modified the method `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()`. I see that the file referenced is in the `local` folder.
By default the method `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml` has only 8 parameters and only the first one is required.
Remove the file from the `local` code pool and see if the error reproduces.